# Как добавить SSH пользователя без HOME директории и без ошибок?

Tags: ubuntu, git, ssh

На сервере есть гит репозиторий. Хочу, чтобы люди клонировали проект, авторизируясь по SSH под своими логинами и паролями.

Если добавлять пользователя `adduser имя_пользователя`, потом генерировать у него ключ через `ssh-keygen` и добавлять ключ в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - всё хорошо, **НО**, если будет 5,10,15,20 пользователей, то папка `home` будет забита хламом с пользователями.

Если создавать пользователя без домашней директории `adduser --no-create-home USER` и далее генерировать у него ключ и добавлять в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` - тоже всё хорошо, **НО**, когда пользователь клонирует проект или отправляет в репозиторий или тянет с репозитория и т.д. - постоянно появляется надпись:

> Could not chdir to home directory /home/USER: No such file or directory

Что логично.

Как можно создать несколько пользователей с паролями, сгенерировать для них ключи, но при этом, чтобы не было их хлама в `home` директории и не было ошибок?

Не хочу трогать настройки `AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`, как это написано тут: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136678/ssh-into-an-account-which-has-no-home-directory, потому что в комментах пишут, что могут возникнуть проблемы

Comment: Возможно глупое предложение, но как насчёт поднять полноценный Git-сервер вроде Gitea? Он и SSH-ключи тоже сам разрулит без создания лишних пользователей в системе

Comment: @andreymal т.к. я только сейчас об этом узнал, то это непосильная ноша будет)  А еще у меня сервер без гуи)

Comment: судя по содержимому ответа (в вопросе не совсем понятно: упоминаются **и** ключи **и** пароли), автор вопроса пытается переизобрести старый добрый [gitolite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gitolite) (он же — ещё более старый и ещё более добрый gitosis)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin до gitosis дочитал https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-на-сервере-Gitosis  . Пока не всё понял. Возможно и правда это правильный путь

Comment: про gitosis не читайте. это экскременты мамонта. читайте про его наследника, переработанного и улучшенного — gitolite. пакет имеется во всех актуальных версиях популярных дистрибутивов.

Comment: @andreymal У меня вопрос - если я установлю Gitea на машине Ubuntu Server (к сожалению есть только такая, без GUI), то как на другой машине можно в её (gitea) гуи залезть?)

Comment: @СергейМишин по протоколу http, gitea это веб-сервер

Comment: @andreymal а можно как-то чуть более подробно узнать? А то у меня сейчас на сервере апач с парочкой сайтов находятся. Я к ним с другой машины могу стучаться только если в hosts пропишу ip машины и alias. Тут что-то подобное придется делать?

Comment: @СергейМишин да, но было бы полезно не пожалеть тысячу рублей в год на покупку домена

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сделать так:

1. Создать главного гит юзера

   `adduser gituser`
2. Создать группу общую

   `sudo addgroup gitusers`
3. `sudo chmod 775 -R /home/gituser`

   `sudo chown -R gituser:gitusers /home/gituser`
4. Поставить права для группы папке `git` (chown -R gituser:gitusers путь/к/гиту)
5. Добавление индивидуального пользователя

   ```
   adduser --no-create-home UserName
   sudo usermod -a -G gitusers UserName
   sudo usermod -d /home/gituser UserName

   su UserName
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "info@thisserver"  --->   /home/gituser/id_rsa.UserName

   exit

   cat  /home/gituser/id_rsa.UserName.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

---

Есл это плохое решение - пожалуйста поделитесь более правильным.

Comment: Неплохо. Еще можно поставить `git-shell` как оболочку, тогда люди не смогут лазить по серваку. или зачрутить на каталог с репо. `то папка home будет забита хламом с пользователями` - это вам не нравится? ну сделайте `/var/home/...`, "хлам" будет там. Хотите сократить хлам, подредактируйте `/etc/skel` - для всех, или `useradd ... --skel /etc/skel-for-git`

Comment: @TotalPusher "Еще можно поставить git-shell как оболочку, тогда люди не смогут лазить по серваку." -  да да, я это хотел делать редактированием `/etc/passwd` с указанием `/bin/sh` вместо `/usr/bin/git-shell`. Просто в ответе не указывал